# Test of goodness of fit - normal distribution of file sizes on HDD

Tags: statistics, data-analysis

I'm trying to prove, that sizes of files stored on HDD comes from normal distribution.

I already made a java code that gave me list of all files on disk with filesizes in Bytes:

```
...
20380 html
21459 html
271 gif
271 gif
145 gif
72 gif
838 gif
...
```

Because of huge amount of files (about 500k) seemed continuous distribution like good idea, I'm aiming to intervals after all, so why would be absence of real numbers a problem.
So the resulting intervals are:

```
...
(400, 520> 12464x
(520, 676> 7157x
(676, 879> 90909x
(879, 1140> 15184x
(1140, 1480> 18992x
(1480, 1920> 17396x
(1920, 2490> 16042x
(2490, 3230> 16132x
(3230, 4190> 14016x
...
```

(http://pastebin.com/CX5tLPV5)

for parameters I have :

$$
\widehat{\mu } = \overline{x} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i}{n} = 844917
$$
$$
\widehat{\sigma} = s = \sqrt{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i - \overline{x})^{2}}{ n - 1 }} = 4281667
$$

from
$$
\pi_{0,i} = F(x_i) - F(x_{i-1})
$$
I expect to get 'expected relative freq.' but what means Xi? Some certain number from i-th interval?

Furthermore, according to wiki
$$
f(x; \mu , \sigma ^2) = \frac{1}{\mu \sqrt{2 \pi}}\cdot e^{-\frac{1}{2}(\frac{x - \mu}{\sigma})^2}
$$
should give me point on bell curve, but it goes for lower sides of intervals

```
... 9.317452E-8
5.6513205E-8
5.6513205E-8
1.26098E-8
1.0350754E-9
1.0350754E-9
3.4722914E-13
1.419046E-15
1.1799776E-21
4.9485846E-34
0.0 ...
```

using tables on the other hand gives me for x=3475374080

$$
u = \frac{x-\mu}{\sigma} = 811
$$

which is quite big.

I'm so confused it can't get any worse I guess. So what am I missing?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! I'm sorry that your question went without a response for a week. Most likely, this is because your question does not fall under *probability*, but rather into statistics or data analysis. There is a [separate StackExchange site](http://stats.stackexchange.com/) for questions on these topics.

Comment: That said, trying to fit filesizes into a normal distribution seems unlikely to produce useful results. Since files are not made by compounding independent chunks; there is no reason for their sizes to follow a normal distribution. Maybe you could begin by comparing the histogram of your data to graphs of commonly used distributions?

Comment: When I painted intervals above into graph, It was pretty much like normal distribution, except for a one tooth around files 600B to 900B on pretty much every system I tested. Of course on exponential scale, on linear scale is it probably colsest to exponential distribution, and with that I loose pretty much all the information, and thus loosing even a slightest chance of predicting the curve.

Comment: So I guess you are actually using the [log-normal distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution)? Then you should be taking the logarithm of each file size, and use those logarithms to calculate $\bar x$ and $\sigma$. The value $\bar x=844917$ does not look like it came from logarithms.